# Java : How to get button position after self click-action

Tags: java, swing

How can i access X-Y coordinates of a button (or any other element) after performing click on itself. My code is,

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Object source2 = evt.getSource(); 
        System.out.println(source2);
}
```

Which prints,

```
javax.swing.JButton[,591,66,74x28,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@59b3c6aa,flags=288
```

So, How can I get `"591"` & `"66"` as integer.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast it to `JButton` after you've checked if it's an `instanceof JButton`, in the example below we're accessing the `x` and `y` value:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
        JButton source2 = (JButton) evt.getSource();

        System.out.println(source2.getX());
        System.out.println(source2.getY());
    }
}
```

Comment: `getX` etc is inherited from `JComponent`. Casting to that is sufficient.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus it sounds good, can you please elaborate via posting answer, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just replace all `JButton` in Mark's answer with `JComponent`